# Where can i find the compile vaadin widgetset in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, vaadin

I'm facing this issue where i'm not able to find the Compile Vaadin widgets button in the main toolbar of Eclipse.
I have installed vaadin plug-in and my eclipse is of below version
Version:

2020-06 (4.16.0)

Build id: 20200615-1200

Can someone help to resolve this?

Comment: Which Vaadin version, and is it a Maven project or Ivy project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `compile widgetset` -button was used with the old Ivy projects, which haven't been the recommended way to use Vaadin for quite some time now, so without knowing which version you are using I'm assuming you've simply run across some very old instructions and the button isn't actually needed.

With Maven projects you can simply right click the project -> `Run as` -> `Maven install`
or  `Run as` -> `Maven build...` -> write `vaadin:compile` to `Goals:` field -> click `Run` (or something similar, I don't have that particular Eclipse version installed).

Comment: I'm using eclipse version 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Comment: @Rajeshs do you have a pom.xml in your project?